# How to use CSS & Bootstrap to create equal sized spaces between blocks of content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ks4yg1h8/2/. I want 2 effects:

**In mobile - currently working**

[image]

All 4 boxes should stack vertically with 20px distance in between

**In desktop/large screens - currently NOT working**

[image]

Vertical 20px between all boxes whether vertically or horizontally speaking

**PROBLEM**

On large screens/desktop, not sure how to create the gap between 2 boxes on upper left and 1 box on upper right. Have tried:

1. Negative margins, but alas I have just read up on the issue with negative margin-right and why that doesn't work.
2. Nest another set of divs inside the main block (the one currently with `background-color`). Also couldn't get it to work

**CODE**

```
<div class="container home-block" id="protips-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div style="text-align:center;"class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <h1>
       headline
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom:20px">
      <!-- the 2 boxes -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:red;height:140px;margin-bottom:20px">
          <h2 class="table-cell-display">test</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:blue;height:140px">
          <h2 class="table-cell-display">test</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style="background-color:green;height:300px;margin-bottom:20px">
      <!-- the single box -->
      <h2 class="table-cell-display">test</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:yellow;height:200px">
      <!-- the last box -->
      <h2 style="width:100%;" class="table-cell-display">test</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can try with @media querys, also you can check the flexbox which works better for me that boostrap

Comment: I'm having a hard time following the desktop version, can you provide an illustration, please?

Comment: @zer00ne yes you can click into the fiddle

Comment: I mean a sketch of how things are supposed to look like.  Make a screen shot of your layout then draw arrows and notes to indicate what and where you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your green div and then tell it to to add some margin based on a media query:

```
@media(min-width: 750px){
  .green-div {
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
  }
}
```

updated jsfiddle = https://jsfiddle.net/ks4yg1h8/4/

UPDATE - 
In order to keep everything evenly sized, also add a class to your left divs and adjust their width minus (half of) the margin

```
@media(min-width: 750px){
  .green-div {
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
  .left-div {
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ks4yg1h8/5/

Comment: in this case, the green div is now narrower than the blue/red div by 20px, is there a way to make them the same width?

Comment: @james Good catch.  Updated my answer for you